# C language, how can I check if a given input is a character or a positive int

Tags: c, while-loop

I want to know how to keep taking inputs from keyboard with this condition: If the given input is a positive number, it keeps going with the code If the given input is a negative number or a letter, it must print "insert a positive number" and then ask again for another input until it has the correct one. About negative and positive inputs the code i wrote works great, but it bugs out when I put a letter. The check I tried is the following

```
chk=isalpha(n);
while(!chk || n<0)
{
    printf("Inserire un intero positivo \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    chk=isalpha(n);
}
printf("%d\n%d\n", t1, t2);
```

In this case if I put a negative number it works correctly, but if I type a letter the printf loops. I also tried `while(isalpha(n) || n<0)` And a bunch of other pieces of code I'll skip for you. Please help me figure this out

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf`. Or ditch it altogether in favor of `fgets`.

Comment: Your question is not really about C.  It is about `scanf`.  If you want to learn C, the best possible advice is: do *not* use scanf.  Ever.

Comment: You can't use `isalpha` to accomplish this. That will check the value of `n` and return true if it's one of the alphabetic character codes. For example, if the user enters 97 it will return true because 97 is the ASCII representation of the letter 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

You can check return value of `scanf` in case of `char` it returns 0 along with that you need to clear the buffer to stop `scanf` consuming the same character.

Example:

```
int ret = 0;
do
{
     char c;
     while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { } /* to clear the bad characters*/

     printf("Inserire un intero positivo \n");
     ret = scanf("%d", &n);
}while(!ret || n<0);
```

Comment: _but if I type a letter the printf loops._ Your code will, too.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp That is what intended behavior. User is supposed  to enter valid number.

Comment: `If the given input is a negative number or a letter, it must print "insert a positive number" and then ask again for another input until it has the correct one. ` This is exactly is OP's need.

Comment: I guess Johnny is meaning that the `scanf` won't consume any input, so it will loop over and over on the same faulty part. https://ideone.com/m95PAD You need to clean up the bad characters before retrying.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Exactly it is. Thank you

Comment: Professor told me to do this way 
while(scanf("%d",&n) != 1 || n<0)
    {
        printf("Inserire un intero positivo\n");
        while(getchar() != '\n');
    }